# How to deal with curl error 2 caused by "Failed getting banner"?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have four Raspberry Pies all running curl 7.64.0. Each Pi uploads a webcam image to the same host every two minutes. That's 30 images per hour for four Pies. This is all done with simple bash shell scripts. Authentication with the host is done by public key.

Normally this works fine, but now and then all or most of the Pies fail with curl error 2 which, according to the log is cause by: "Failure establishing ssh session: -13, Failed getting banner".

I understand that this is not caused by an error in curl, however, I wonder if there is some way I can overcome the error with curl.

Right now I'm using the following parameters:

--connect-timeout 10
--max-time 120
--retry 5
I set max-time to 120 because images are uploaded every two minutes. The other two are just guesses on my part as to what might work.

Here's the complete curl command:

```
    curl -s -v -u me: \
     --connect-timeout 10 \
     --max-time 120 \
     --retry 5 \
     --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
     -T $file $host >> $log 2>&1
```

Where:

```
$file is: the file to be uploaded
$host is: host=sftp://ftp.me.com/~/public_html/
$log  is: the local log file
```

Here's the verbose curl output:

```
*   Trying nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x3698b0)
* Connected to ftp.mgnewman.com (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn) port 22 (#0)
* Failure establishing ssh session: -13, Failed getting banner
* Closing connection 0
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: How does `ssh` relate to this, give us the full command not just the parameters? What is the process picking up the images on the server? What's the server OS?

Comment: I edited the question to include the full curl command as well as the complete curl verbose output. I believe the host uses CentOS7. The images are just part of a web page: [Cha Am Webcam](https://www.mgnewman.com/chaamkam.php) The upload replaces an image with the same file name. As noted, this works almost all of the time with a handful of errors on each Pi every day.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much of an answer to the question, but it is one solution to the problem. I've surrounded the curl command with a do loop. It seems that curl doesn't consider the "Failed getting banner" error to be a connection error, so it doesn't "retry"; it just times out. Here's what I'm using:

```
for i in {1..3}
 do

    curl -s -v -u mgnewman: \
     --connect-timeout 25 \
     --max-time 40 \
     --retry 3 \
     --pubkey ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
     -T $file $host >> $log 2>&1

        err=$?
        echo $'\n'"`date`" Upload Ended "$err" - $(hostname) >> "$log"


        if [ $err -eq 0 ] ; then
                break
        fi
done
```

It's ugly, but there are no more curl 2 errors on any of the four Pies.